# introduction of an unbounded factor to a given convergent series and also to a divergent one, each series of positive terms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I cannot manage to prove this theorem:

Let $c_n$ and $d_n$ be sequences of non-negative reals, defined for all $n \geq 1.\,\,$ Assume

1. $\,\,\,\,\sum c_n\,=\,L,\,\,$ with $\,\,\,0 < L < + \infty.\,\,$ Denote a partial sum as $C_n.$
2. $\,\,\,\,\sum d_n\,=\, \,\,\,+ \infty.\,\,\,\,\,\,$ Denote a partial sum as $D_n.$
3. $\,\,\,\,\sum n c_n\,=\, + \infty.\,\,\,\,\,\,$ Denote a partial sum as $\Gamma_n.$

From the above follows that $\,\,\,\,\sum n d_n\,=\, + \infty.\,\,\,\,\,\,$ Denote a partial sum as $\Delta_n.$

The claim is that for some index $m$, we must have $\Gamma_m\,<\,\Delta_m.$

I have tried a number of things. The negation of the conclusion is that  $\sum n(c_n\,-\,d_n)$ is never negative. However it follows from 1. and 2. that $\sum (c_n\,-\,d_n)\,=\,- \infty.$ This seems promising, for a contradiction.

An easy observation is that we must have $c_n\,-\,d_n\,<\,0$ infinitely often. In particular, this must happen for a first time.

Also, i tried to find some applicable theorems. For instance the form of the sequences $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ made me try the theorem (for $n\to\infty$) that says:

$$\frac{c_1\,+\,2c_2\,+\,\dots\,+\,n c_n}{n}\,\to\,0,$$
and of course the fact that $c_n \to 0$ might be useful. No luck with this so far.

I also considered the ratio $\Gamma_n / \Delta_n$, that could be a better thing to attack, maybe? All that is needed is an $m$ with $\Gamma_m / \Delta_m < 1.$ For this idea, I was getting hopeful about the Cauchy, Toeplitz, Stolz-Cesaro type theorems, but those often require strictly monotone denominators. (so maybe i need to ditch the zeros in either $c_n$ or $d_n$?)

Lastly, $C_n$ is of course Cauchy. At this point, I am suspecting the proof is bleeding easy, and I am have just struck out so far. I'd appreciate any hint, other relevant theorems, whatever! thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick that I see is to write $D_m$ in terms of the $\Delta_n$ via summation by parts. If we had $\Delta_m \leqslant \Gamma_m$ for all $m$ it would follow that $D_m \leqslant C_m$ for all $m$, hence $\sum d_n < +\infty$.

Don't hover over the following before you've tried yourself.

> \begin{align} D_m &= \sum_{n = 1}^m d_n \\ &= \sum_{n = 1}^m \frac{\Delta_n - \Delta_{n-1}}{n} \\ &= \sum_{n = 1}^m \frac{\Delta_n}{n} - \sum_{n = 0}^{m-1} \frac{\Delta_n}{n+1} \\ &= \frac{\Delta_m}{m} + \sum_{n = 1}^{m-1} \frac{\Delta_n}{n(n+1)}\end{align} using $\Delta_0 = 0$. Doing the same for $C_m$ shows that $\Delta_n \leqslant \Gamma_n$ for $n \leqslant m$ implies $D_m \leqslant C_m$.

Comment: Yes, that works fantastically. Your hint was enough; I produced essentially the same thing using your suggestion, before I hovered. Note to self: do not neglect Abel's transformation/ by-parts summation. THANK YOU